# Distribute fixed number of users to each class in locust

Tags: locust

I am working on a dumy website as part of learning Locust. I have complete dthe scripting but only thing left is "how to distribute a particular number of users to user classes

```
class MainClass(TaskSet):
   

   

    @task
    class Class1(SequentialTaskSet):

        @task
        def Method-1(self):

            

        @task
        def Method-2(self):
            

    @task
    class Class2(SequentialTaskSet):
   

             

       @task
       def Method-3(self):


       @task
       def Method-4(self):
            



class Main(HttpUser):
    tasks = {Class1, Class2}
    host = "http://localhost:9090"
    wait_time = constant(5)
```

I want ru nthe test with total 50users and distribution should be as follows
--30 users to Class1
--20 users to Class2.

How to distribute the users as pe rthe above modelling.

Also I gave WEIGHT to the claases as   tasks = {Class1:3, Class2:2}
But this weight is only distributing the total requests in the ratio of 3:2 and not the users. I want the exact user count to be 30 and 20.

Please have a look at the issue.

Comment: Your post is very long. Please remove everything not related to User distribution, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. And describe the undesired result you are getting. "not distributing users properly" and "but it is not working" is very unclear.